# Winui3 - Navigationview default color white instead of grayscale

Tags: c#, winui-3, navigationview

I'am a little bit confused. I created a Navigationview and my expectation was, that the color is like that. Which means, two different gray scales.

[Winui3 Gallery Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To1RV.png)

But in my case it looks like fully white. I thought the default colors are gray scales?

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZs0s.png)

I know that I can change the pane background but it makes no sense, because in the WinUi3 Gallery I didnt find such a property. It looks like that there the colors are default

```
        <NavigationView.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewTopPaneBackground"
                             Color="Red" />
        </NavigationView.Resources>
```

So do you know what I have to do to get the default colors like in WinUI3 Gallery for Light and dark theme?

Comment: The `NavigationView` should give you those 2 colors by default. Can you post reproducible code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce it. Due to Winui3 Gallery uses the `NavigationViewHeaderTemplate` HeaderTemplate whose background is transparent and the Grid's Background is `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` there are two different gray scales. Note that Winui3 Gallery has updated its code.

[image: reproduced]
[image: code]
[image: example]